# Is $x^x$ in the same asymptotic growth class as an exponential function?

Tags: asymptotics, exponential-function, exponentiation

I see that for any natural number $a$, $\lim_{x\to\infty} \tfrac{x^x}{a^x}$ approaches $\infty$, so the limit does not exist. So is this function have a different big-O than $O(a^x)$, for example? So what are the complexity classes beyond exponential time like this, if it's not factorial?

Comment: It's in a different class. In order for it to be in the same class, some constant multiple of x^x would have to (eventually) be bounded above by a^x. This never happens, and that is a direct consequence of the limit you mentioned being infinite.

Comment: As you observed $x^x$ in the long run grows significantly faster than any $a^x$ with $a$ fixed. So $x^x$ is not $O(a^x)$.

Comment: You kind of answered in your question, didn't you? Perhaps it might help to write $x^x=\exp(x\cdot \ln(x))$.

Comment: Thank you all. Edited question to ask about what, if any, big-o this would fall under. Or would this be classified as super-exponentiation?

Comment: re: your edit: There are many different classes which grow more quickly than a^x. In fact, if you have O(f(x)), you can make a "faster growing" class just by taking x*f(x). Some examples are O(n!), O(x^x), O(x*e^x), etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For large $x$, no question of what to do with $0^0$ arises and we may write $x^x = \mathrm{e}^{x \ln x}$ and $a^x = \mathrm{e}^{x \ln a}$.  Note that $x \ln x$ always out-grows $x \ln a$, so there is no $a$ such that $x^x \in O(a^x)$.

(In fact, your observation about the infinite limit is sufficient to establish this.)

However, $x^x = \mathrm{e}^{x \ln x} \in O(\mathrm{e}^{x^2})$...

Comment: But $e^{x^2}\notin O(x^x)?$

Comment: @SimpleArt : Definitely so.  $\mathrm{e}^{x^2} / \mathrm{e}^{x \ln x} \rightarrow \infty$.